# Delete list on last item remove with connected JQuery sortable and knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Tvp/1/

### Steps to Reproduce

Drag Temperature list item under Score List

### Expected Behaviour

The now empty list where the temperature list item existed should be deleted, as the last element in the list has been removed.

### Actual Behaviour

The empty list remains in the GUI.

Comment: Can you describe this a little more?  I am not sure that I quite understand the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added some more detail about expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to put a visible binding on the category template like:

```
<script id="obsGroupCatTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div style="float: left;" data-bind="visible: ObservationGroups().length">
```

Not sure if you actually need category removed or if hiding it is sufficient.  If necessary, you could setup a manual subscription to each observableArray of ObservationGroups in the category object.  If the array gets to the point where it is empty, then you could remove it completely from the ObservationGroupCategories array.

Comment: Removing the category would be preferable, as the above code results in new observation group categories being hidden by default. Could you give me some hints as to setting up a manual subscription in this case?

Comment: Would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/U3Tvp/2/  Basically pass the parent to the ObservationGroupCategory constructor.  Set up a subscription to ObservationGroups.  If the new value is null or the length of the array is 0, then remove the category from the parent.

Comment: Looks good, but this causes the category to be duplicated in the list. Try moving temperature to under score. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: Looks like a subtle timing issue.  Looks like we want to remove the category after all of the updates are done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/U3Tvp/3/